# Django: How to update a IntegerField based on previous ChoiceField, but keep it editable?

Tags: python, django, web, django-models, django-forms

I hava the following form:

```
class form1(forms.ModelForm):
    CHOICES = (('EASY', 'EASY'), ('MEDIUM', 'MEDIUM'), ('HARD', 'HARD'))
    dificulty = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES)
    xp = forms.IntegerField()
```

I want to change the xp field based on the dificulty field choice.

Like, if the user put EASY on dificulty, change xp to 30. But keeping it editable, so the user can specify if it will be 31 or 29, or something like that.

Comment: You could probably implement something like this by manipulating the form's `cleaned_data` inside the forms' `clean` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form's `clean` method will come handy here

```
class form1(forms.ModelForm):
    DEFAULT_XP_MAP = ('EASY': 30, 'MEDIUM': ...)
    CHOICES = (('EASY', 'EASY'), ('MEDIUM', 'MEDIUM'), ('HARD', 'HARD'))
    dificulty = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES)
    xp = forms.IntegerField()

    def _get_default_xp(difficulty):
        return self.DEFAULT_XP_MAP.get(difficulty, None)

    def clean():
        cleaned_data = super(form1, self).clean()
        difficulty = cleaned_data.get('difficulty')
        xp = cleaned_data.get('xp')
        if difficulty and not xp:  # Set defaults
            cleaned_data['xp'] = self._get_default_xp(difficulty)
        return cleaned_data
```

To achieve the same thing on the FE using jQuery you can do:

```
(function () {
  $ = window.jQuery;
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var default_xp_map = {
        'EASY': 30,
        'MEDIUM': 60, 
        'HARD': 90,
    };
    var $difficulty = $("#difficulty");  // Difficulty form input field
    var $xp = $('#xp');  // XP form input field
    $difficulty.on('blur', function() {
        if ($difficulty.val() && !$xp.val()) {  // Difficulty is set; but xp is not set 
            $xp.val(default_xp_map[$difficulty.val()]);
        }
    });
  });
})();
```

Comment: Almost but i wanted to make it appear in the xp integer field the number.

Comment: Then you need custom admin js!

Comment: @RonaldoSilveira Updated the answer; is that what you were looking for?

Comment: THANK YOU! But in which file do i put it?

Comment: Put it in a new file and link it up using `class Media` in Django admin:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/media/#assets-as-a-static-definition